# "!" After typing, press the "TAB" key on the keyboard. This method is not working in Pycharm

Tags: python, html, pycharm, structure, doctype

I wanted to complete my html doctype construct but it's like impossible to do it,
please tell me what to do.

I tried to write:

> '<!' then nothings appear

Comment: Did you check if the format of your file is .html and not .py ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.